# I was upgrading ubuntu 20.04 to ubuntu 20.10 and my computer's power went out and now it says emergency status at startup?

Tags: boot, gnome, mount

```
Failed failed to mount Mount unit for gnome-3-26-1604, revision 98
Failed Failed to mount Mount unit for gnome-3-28-1804, revision 128
Failed Failed to mount Mount unit for gnome-3-28-1804, revision 145
Failed Failed to mount Mount unit for gnome-3-28-1804, revision 60
Failed Failed to mount Mount unit for gnome-3-28-1804, revision 66
Failed Failed to mount Mount unit for gnome-system monitor, revision 145
Failed Failed to mount Mount unit for gnome-system monitor, revision 148
Failed Failed to mount Mount unit for......
Failed Failed to mount Mount unit for....
Failed Failed to mount Mount unit for.....
Failed Failed to mount Mount unit for.....
Failed Failed to mount Mount unit for......

you are in emergency mode. After logging in, tye "jornalctl -xb" to view system logs,"systemctl reboot" to reboot, "systemctl default" or "exit" to boot into default mode.
Pulse enter para mantenimiento
(o punse Control -D para continuar)
```

Comment: For anyone wondering, translating the ending sentence: `Click Enter for maintenance (or press Control + D to continue)`

Comment: Since the power was cut off, there's probably not a feasible solution to your problem except to reinstall the operating system. You can use a live session to retrieve files off this installation in case you forgot to make backups.

Comment: look that I have tried, I set the BIOS to BOOT but the GNU GRUB startup screen does not allow reading the USB, what can I do?